# What are the exact powers of a superuser?

Tags: shell, privileges

What are the exact powers for a super user? Would the have privileges to disable a standard users ls command?

For example: If I ran the command:

```
ls
```

And the output I received was:

```
This is a fake ls!
```

Who would have access to doing this? Would it be a superuser or an attacker?

Comment: I don't see what is the correlation between what you see and superuser. What exactly you want to ask? What a superuser is capable of, or who is messing with ls?

Answer (score 2):

Basic commands like `ls` are actually programs like every other. `ls` is located at `/bin/ls` and part of the GNU coreutils (but that's just a titbit of information).

Superuser privileges (called root privileges in common) allow you to do **everything** with your system. Actually, it does not in every case, there are mechanisms like SELinux which aim to prevent malicious actions, but that's another story. Most likely you are not running a system which enforces SELinux policies (as it is aimed at servers and high-security infrastructure). Back to topic, someone with root privileges could replace the program located at `/bin/ls` with everything - For example a bash script or another program. Therefore, the

> This is a fake ls!

output is possible if someone was able to access your system with root privileges.

Comment: It should also be said that a command like `ls` you type in a shell (command line) is searched in a number of PATHs - i.e. directories. The order in which they are searched is relevant. In DOS/Windows the current working directory `.` is included in the PATH, in Linux/UNIX it is not, for security reasons. However, if you put `.` inside the PATH environment variable and it stands before `/bin` then `ls` could be an executable file `./ls`, not `/bin/ls`. A non-superuser may well be able to write a file `ls` in a directory other than `/bin`. To find out which `ls` is used you can type `which ls`.

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is caused either by `/bin/ls` being replaced by a program that outputs `This is a fake ls!` or an alias set in your bash environment on the command `ls`.

Altering `/bin/ls` would require root privileges. The superuser acts with root privileges. The attacker may have gained root privileges. Adding an alias would only require your user's privileges.

Test by running `ls` with the command `/bin/ls` (in the absolute path). If the message `This is a fake ls!` appears, the `ls` program has been altered, if not, then an alias has been set. View your aliases with the command `alias`, edit them in `~/.bashrc` (assuming you use a bash shell).